# Как выводить в одном модальном окне данные из разных карточек товара по клику на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! есть модальное окно и много карточек товара, при клике на кнопку в карточке товара должно открываться модальное окно с отображением данных из карточки их 20. Можно ли реализовать на js?

```
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    var btn = document.getElementById("card-1");

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "flex";
 }

    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};
};
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/974625/256824

Comment: Можно. Реализуйте.